# Separation of variables PDES- separation constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

Why is the separation constant $-\lambda^2$ and not just $-\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is 
$$
y'' + k^2x = A\sin(kx) + B\cos(kx)
$$
rather than
$$
y'' + kx = A\sin(\sqrt{k}x) + B\cos(\sqrt{k}x)
$$
i.e. Not a square root in sight.

Since it is a constant we can write $\lambda^2$ as confidently as we can write it as $\lambda$.

As pointed out in the comments - Using $\lambda^2$ we are being explicit that $\lambda^2 > 0$ so taking a sqrt of the constant is not more complex (no pun intended).

Comment: The square also reminds us that it is positive.

Comment: @Ian Agreed. The positivity.